# How to disable automatic file compression in my Linux server

Tags: php, linux, apache, ftp, cpanel

One of my client's site is hosted in a linux based server (managing with CPanel). When I published the site, I gone through a strange issue.

All files in the server (for some particular folders) are compressed. I am not talking about GZIP or related compression. Even when I upload a file and open the file from the server, every spaces and linebreaks are strippedof.

Stripping all spaces and linebreaks creates several code error (mainly with comments). So I need to stop this behavior.

Please help me to resolve this issue by some how. I have server controls through CPanel (Having a limited control). Let me inform you that this issue is visible only for certain folders.

Comment: Are you just opening it as a webpage? If so, it will try and parse it as HTML. Try viewing the source.

Comment: How are you uploading the files to the server?

Comment: In first, I thought it was related to web page compression. But I was wrong. If I put comment (//) in PHP code, that also gives parse error.

Comment: I am uploading files through FTP. When I open the file on server in a text editor, I can see the codes without spaces and linebreaks.

Comment: This is not a programming issue, so it's off-topic for StackOverflow.  You should probably contact the hosting company (who runs the FTP server) and have them help you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your FTP program is in Text Mode and for some reason it's stripping out all whitespace. That is not normal, but try uploading in Binary Mode to see if that works around the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but it is little late. You said the right answer. I already found this answer and resolved the issue. The FTP server may have some problem which is not decompressing ascii mode FTP transfer in server side.